# Android app crashes while startActivityForResult using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent with external file

Tags: android, android-intent, crash

I have for me a bit strange problem and I can't find out, what is the problem. I need to obtain high resolution image for my application. I have decided to use build-in camera app. I have seen this website https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html and in my opinion, I have done it exactly the same. But when i try to call startActivityForResult my application crashes immediately. I have read I need to use onSaveInstanceState(), but it wouldn't crush immediately, before taking an image. Please, could you advise me, what is wrong.

Here is a code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode==TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST){
        if (resultCode!=RESULT_OK) return;
            // to know call was successful
        Toast.makeText(this, "Result received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private static final String TAKEN_PHOTO_FILE_NAME="/_TAKEN_IMAGE_.jpg";
private Uri takenImageUri;
protected void button_takePhoto_click(View v){
    Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File outImage = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + TAKEN_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
    takenImageUri=Uri.fromFile(outImage);
        // if I comment line below out, everything works.
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, takenImageUri); 
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `super.onActivityResult(args...)` behind owerridable body.